# Jasper Reports Excel output

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I need to generate a report in Excel format using Jasperreports. I am using iReports 3.7.0
The reports gets generated with no issues except the size of empty cells.

[image]

Can somebody please tell how to avoid the highlighted cell being enlarged. Also the normal cells are also a little larger than their content.

Answer (score 14):

Also,I would say stick to basics when you need to export Japser to XLS. I mean no graphics, and more.

The above solution is good for generating XLS from iReport.

If you would like to generate XLS thru program; use the following code

```
exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used the latest package JExcelExporter.

Answer (score 2):

Also - if you're deploying to jasperserver you can set the custom properties within the report. (iReport doesn't do this automatically)

In the properties of the main report element add:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows
```

and set them all to true

Comment: Also use `net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text` to avoid truncating overflowing values